# Play Framework 2.7 Authorization Get User

Tags: java, playframework, play-framework-2.7

I'm trying to add authorization to a Rest API I've built in Play 2.7. I found a good example for older play versions [here](https://github.com/jamesward/play-rest-security/tree/master/app/controllers) but I do not have access to the Http Context so I cannot add the user as an arg.

Is there another way to do [this](https://github.com/jamesward/play-rest-security/blob/master/app/controllers/Secured.java) in Play 2.7 without having access to the context?

```
public class Secured extends Security.Authenticator {

    @Override
    public String getUsername(Context ctx) {
        String[] authTokenHeaderValues = ctx.request().headers().get(SecurityController.AUTH_TOKEN_HEADER);
        if ((authTokenHeaderValues != null) && (authTokenHeaderValues.length == 1) && (authTokenHeaderValues[0] != null)) {
            User user = models.User.findByAuthToken(authTokenHeaderValues[0]);
            if (user != null) {
                ctx.args.put("user", user);
                return user.getEmailAddress();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Result onUnauthorized(Context ctx) {
        return unauthorized();
    }
}
```

I'm wanting to have the ability to get the user from other controllers as they have done in the Todo Controller.

Edit: My question comes down to where do you store the authenticated User in Play 2.7, since Http.Context is deprecated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Action Composition**

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/JavaActionsComposition#Passing-objects-from-action-to-controller

```
public class Attrs {
    public static final TypedKey<User> USER = TypedKey.<User>create("user");
}

public class PassArgAction extends play.mvc.Action.Simple {
    public CompletionStage<Result> call(Http.Request req) {
        return delegate.call(req.addAttr(Attrs.USER, User.findById(1234)));
    }
}
```

In controller:

```
@With(PassArgAction.class)
public static Result passArgIndex(Http.Request request) {
    User user = request.attrs().get(Attrs.USER);
    return ok(Json.toJson(user));
}
```

I will recommend you also to look at **pac4j**. It has a plugin for playframework:

https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j

https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j-java-demo

Comment: Thanks, the action composition is exactly what I'm looking for. Unfortunately, pac4j doesn't support play 2.7 from what I can see.

Comment: yeah, they are not so fast in implementing new versions, but they are working on.